# Need to know about AWS Database is there are multiple database or single?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to know a little bit about the AWS cloud database. As we use a database like MySQL and another side we have firebase. So firebase is a cloud database so AWS is something similar to firebase or not?

In the AWS website, I see in database service there are many options like Amazon Dynamo DB, Amazon DocumentDB, etc these are a database or something else? I need to move now to AWS so I need to know is there are many databases in AWS or one? So I can start connected my Flask Rest APIs with AWS database for practice. (So just need to know there are multiple databases in AWS or single.)

Comment: There are many DBs. If you are after managed MySQL solution, then RDS or RDS Aurora should be investigated.

Comment: First search result: https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple **database services** available in AWS.

Traditional databases are available in the **Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS)**. This provides MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server. Each database runs on its own virtual server and is fully dedicated to your account. There is an additional type called **Amazon Aurora**, which has a MySQL or PostgreSQL front-end, but uses AWS technology in the back-end to be highly scalable and resilient. It even has an **Aurora Serverless** option that automatically scales based on load.

**Amazon DynamoDB** is another popular database, which is serverless (meaning it is always available, no need to create/start/stop the database). It is a **NoSQL database** rather than a relational database. This gives it amazing performance and guaranteed access times, but you can't run SQL queries against the data.

All the [remaining databases](https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/) are specialized around techniques like graph database, time series database, immutable database or compatible with Cassandra and Mongo.